# How to substitute some letters in a multi-length word consisting of digits and letters in a specific format?

Tags: linux, text-processing, command-line, awk, sed

I have a file in which I want to change all of the code that has the following format : `n{,3}L{,2}n{,5} where n= [0-9] any number and L [a-zA-Z] any letter either capital or not`

I want to change A or a into AB and d or D into DK, something like this:

```
 Annnnn--> ABnnnnn ; Dnnn-->DKnnn
```

the file looks like:

```
$ cat filename
123a67,64,xx
A67990,12,ttt
89d7,34,ggg
234AB445,78,ooo
145aB7699,67,rrr
278Dk89,25,ppp
```

I tried the following sed script

```
sed 's/[aA]/AB/g;s/[dD]/DK/g' filename
```

it works for instances which have only A or D but for those which are already AB or DK it adds up the letter as `AB--> ABB or DK-->DKK`. Any help appreciated with explanation. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for what's wrong with your script, you are replacing `A` or `a` with `AB` and `D` or `d` with `DK`, so any pre-existing `B` or `K` would not be affected; `sed` is not looking for it. You could put an optional `[bB]` or `[kK]` using `?` (zero or one of the preceding character) to make it replace that character too if it occurs.

To make sure the replacement only happens if `[aA]` or `[aA][bB]` etc is followed by a number, you can add the number to the pattern and add it back in the replacement with `()` and `\1`

```
sed -r 's/ab?([0-9])/AB\1/Ig;s/dk?([0-9])/DK\1/Ig' filename
```

I am using `-r` to use ERE (so no need to escape `?`) and `I` for case-insensitive search instead of using character classes.

Comment: @Daniel it's a pleasure :D

Comment: a Question! I just realized that your script would not successful if there would be another letter already in the filename. for instance it will also change the `nnAYnnn--> nnABYnnn` which I do not want to see such change and want to keep this intact and observe only changes for code has only  **"A" or "AB"**.  Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: @Daniel ah so, if we have [Aa], change it to [AB] **only if** the next character after [Aa] is [0-9], or [bB] and then [0-9]?

Comment: Yes, Exactly! :)

Comment: @Daniel I've edited, I think I understood correctly, please comment if not :)

Comment: You are awesome! Thanks a lot and I learn many thing from you :) Best.